Exception message: Deprecated Functionality: round(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($num) of type int|float is deprecated in magento 2.4.6
I updated my php version is 8.3 and magento version is 2.4.6
currently facing issue with round functionality.
Exception message: Deprecated Functionality: round(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($num) of type int|float is deprecated
Fee.php
$amount = $invoice->getHandlingCharges();
        $amount += round($invoice->getHandlingChargesTax(), 3, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);

        $baseAmount = $invoice->getBaseHandlingCharges();
        $baseAmount += round($invoice->getBaseHandlingChargesTax(), 3, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);

        $invoice->setGrandTotal($invoice->getGrandTotal() + $amount);
        $invoice->setBaseGrandTotal($invoice->getBaseGrandTotal() + $baseAmount);

        return $this;

please help

The exception was thrown because of null value passed to php round function.
These lines
   $amount += round($invoice->getHandlingChargesTax(), 3, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
   $baseAmount += round($invoice->getBaseHandlingChargesTax(), 3, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP)

should be replaced with
$amount += ($invoice->getHandlingChargesTax()) ? round($invoice->getHandlingChargesTax(), 3, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) : 0;

$baseAmount += ($invoice->getBaseHandlingChargesTax()) ? round($invoice->getBaseHandlingChargesTax(), 3, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) : 0;
    


Change your round function to handle null parameters like this, add ??""
round($invoice->getHandlingChargesTax()??"", 3, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);

wherever your get null exception do like this?
